# How to Show different views for same url Angular 6 (for Progressive Web Apps)

Tags: angular, typescript, user-agent, progressive-web-apps, angular6

Here is the code of my app-router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DheaderComponent } from './dheader/dheader.component';
import { DdashboardComponent } from './ddashboard/ddashboard.component';
import { MdashboardComponent } from './mdashboard/mdashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path:'', component:DheaderComponent},
    { path:'dashboard', if(1){component: DdashboardComponent } else { component :MdashboardComponent} },
    { path:'mdashboard',component:MdashboardComponent},
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]

})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Is it feasible to show **DdashboardComponent** for **Desktop** and **MdashboardComponent** for **Mobile users** for same path that is **path:'dashboard'**.
 If it is how I can achieve and what are the best practices to do it?

Comment: Take a look at this (long) thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15275

Comment: One of the developer mentioned you can have two components **AdminComponent** and **NotadminComponent** then is it feasible to show two different components for a single link path:'admin' in this case!

Comment: This is a more related thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12088

Answer (score 0):

Ideal PWA solution would be to make your page responsive, so it can show relevant content depending on the screen size.

But if you want to show totally content depending on device, only thing you can do is to find the run-time device type(screen resolution, OS etc) and use that info in a common home Javascript code to route to appropriate component(like one of two you have mentioned). There is no explicit way to define component based on device type.